# Фрагменты, ссылки на фрагменты

Tags: android-sdk, android

Чем отличается такое присвоение ссылки на фрагмент

```
    Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_1)).setText("");
```

от (`Fragment_1` — класс реализующий фрагмент)

```
    Fragment_1 frag1 = new Fragment_1();
    frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_1)).setText("");
```

На сколько я понимаю, ссылка присваивается на один и тот же layout файл, но работает только первый вариант! Почему?

Comment: Возможно из-за того, что создается новый экземпляр объекта **Fragment_1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В первом случае вы получаете ссылку на фрагмент, зарегистрированный в активити, для которого уже были вызваны методы жизненного цикла, в т.ч. загрузка и отображение разметки. При этом, если фрагмент вы на самом деле не добавляли (или уже удалили) то вы получите `null`
2. Во втором - вы создаёте экземпляр класса фрагмента, для которого вызывается только его конструктор. В активити он не добавлен, засим его методы жизненного цикла не были вызваны системой и его разметка не загружена.

**Вывод**: доступ к разметке фрагмента можно получить только добавив его в активити и получив его из активити.